# Redirect url to the last accessed page instead of home page using spring

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring 3.1 version.

I have implemented spring security for login to my web portal. It works fine except for one issue. I have set session timeout to 2 min.

Once timeout happpens and then user click any URL, It gets redirected to logout page. But when user re autheticates, user directly lands on the home page which is default target URL instead of last access page.

Like if user is accessed `/home/editproduct` then after timeout & when he again reautenticate he should be accessed to the `home/editproduct` instead of only /home page.

Here is my applicationcontext.xml file :

```
<bean id="myNeAdminUserNamePasswordAuthFilter"
    class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.adminuser.MyNeAdminUserPasswordAuthFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myNeAdminUserAuthManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="adminFailureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="adminSuccessHandler" />

        <property name="authenticationInputProcessor" ref="myNeAdminUserAuthInputProcessor"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="adminSuccessHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/bookShelfController.htm" />

         <property name="useReferer" value="true"/>    
    </bean>
<bean id="adminFailureHandler"
        class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.adminuser.AdminUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/adminlogin.htm"></property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: <bean id="adminSuccessHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
  <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/bookShelfController.htm" />
  
   <property name="useReferer" value="true"/>    
 </bean>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

`ExceptionTranslationFilter` will save the request to `RequestCache` before redirect to entry point, and `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` will try to get the request target url and then redirect to the saved URL.

```
<bean id="adminSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

[More see here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

Comment: Hi i add a custom sucessHandler and implement that class from SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler that works fine from me.

Comment: I add something more, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259471/redirect-to-previous-url-after-timeout/41261668#41261668

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way and it seems to be fine for me

```
public class AdminUrlAutenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler/*SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler*/ {
    //private String defaultFailureUrl;
    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    public RequestCache getRequestCache() {
        return requestCache;
    }

    public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    if (savedRequest == null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null) {
            String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("url_prior_login");
            if (redirectUrl != null) {
                session.removeAttribute("url_prior_login");
                getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
            } else {
                super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }

        return;
    }

    String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
    if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
            || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
        requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

        return;
    }

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);

    // Use the DefaultSavedRequest URL
    String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
    logger.debug("Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: " + targetUrl);
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
}
```

Application-context.xml file

```
<bean id="myNeAdminUserNamePasswordAuthFilter"
 class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.adminuser.MyNeAdminUserPasswordAuthFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myNeAdminUserAuthManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="adminFailureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="adminSuccessHandler" />

        <property name="authenticationInputProcessor" ref="myNeAdminUserAuthInputProcessor"></property>
    </bean>


<bean id="adminSuccessHandler"
        class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.adminuser.AdminUrlAutenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/bookShelfController.htm" />
         <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="spring-security-redirect"/>   
         <property name="useReferer" value="false"/>    
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminFailureHandler"    class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.adminuser.AdminUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/adminlogin.htm"></property>
    </bean>
```

Any suggestion how to do this in different way.

Comment: when did you set the "url_prior_login" into session ? and I think use `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is ok, why you need to override again ?