# Redirect to Previous url after TIMEOUT

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring 3.1 version.

I have implemented spring security for login to my web portal. It works fine except for one issue. I have set session timeout to 2 min.

Once timeout happens and then user click any URL, It gets redirected to logout page. But when user re authenticates, user directly lands on the home page which is default target URL instead of last access page.

Like if user is accessed `/home/editproduct` then after timeout & when he again reautenticate he should be accessed to the `home/editproduct` instead of only `/home` page.

i am using spring with JSON & AJAX call.

```
<bean id="myNePublicUserNamePasswordAuthFilter"
class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.publicuser.MyNePublicUserPasswordAuthFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/service/json_authentication_check"></property>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myNePublicUserAuthenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationInputProcessor" ref="myNePublicUserAuthInputProcessor"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="successHandler"
class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.publicuser.MyNePublicUserAuthSuccessHandler">
    <property name="authHandlerView" ref="authHandlerView"></property>
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"></property>
    <property name="publicLoginManager" ref="publicLoginManager"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect url to the last accessed page instead of home page using spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217617/redirect-url-to-the-last-accessed-page-instead-of-home-page-using-spring)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: For `SessionManagementFilter`**

You need to implement the `InvalidSessionStrategy`, override the `onInvalidSessionDetected` method, just like `SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy`, but before redirect, you need to create a new session, and save the request to session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getsession(false);
if (session != null) {
    // for creating a new session
    session.invalidate();
}
DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request,
                    new PortResolverImpl());
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST", savedRequest);
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, destinationUrl);
```

and then inject this bean to `SessionManagementFilter`.

**EDIT: For ConcurrentSessionFilter**

If you use the concurrentSessionFilter, you can implement `SessionInformationExpiredStrategy`, just like `SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy`, and in the method `onExpiredSessionDetected`, still do the same thing like I post above, before redirect, create new session, and put the save request to new session, you can get the requestby event.getRequest(), then inject this `sessionInfomationExpiredStrategy` to `concurrentSessionFilter`.

```
public void onExpiredSessionDetected(SessionInformationExpiredEvent event) throws IOException {
    logger.debug("Redirecting to '" + destinationUrl + "'");
    DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(event.getRequest(),
                        new PortResolverImpl());
    request.getSession(true).setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST", savedRequest);
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(event.getRequest(), event.getResponse(), destinationUrl);
}
```

Finally , Using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. It will try to get the request target url and then redirect to the saved URL.

Comment: This is my filter class.<bean id="concurrentSessionFilter" class="com.magic.spring.security.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <property name="sessionRegistry">
   <ref bean="sessionRegistry" />
  </property>
  <property name="expiredUrl" value="/webapp/staticcontent/html/PublicLogin.html" />
  <property name="logoutHandlers">
   <list>
    <ref bean="publicUserSessionCleanupLogoutHandler" />
    <!--<ref bean="rememberMeServices" /> -->
    <ref bean="publicSecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: I add some about the concurrentSessionFilter, see above

Comment: BTW, You must invalid your session in logout handler

Comment: I got error on 3.1 version for SessionInformationExpiredEvent class.so have u any other idea or can u provide me suggestion how will i implement this on SuccessHandler class of onAuthenticationSuccess() method.

Comment: when i inject into filter class i got NoClassDefFoundError.